# Как вызвать callback в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, callback

У меня код довольно запутанный, поэтому я миниатюрно опишу что я хочу.
(У меня нет никакой ошибки , просто не могу вызвать callback)

```
ABC = random.randint(1000, 9999) # допустим ABC это рандомное число

qiwiMenu = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
btnCheckQIWI = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Проверить оплату", callback_data="check_"+ABC) # добавляем к "check_" рандомное число (ABC)
qiwiMenu.add(btnCheckQIWI)

@bot.callback_query_handler(lambda callback: True)
def check(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
```

Теперь вопрос, как правильно построить callback_query_handler чтобы он принимал значение "check_"???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(lambda callback: callback.data.startswith("check_"))
```

Comment: который раз меня уже выручаешь , дай бог тебе здоровья мужик)

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(text_contains='check_')
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]